# Screen rotating regardless of the power status of the monitor. Ubuntu 18

Tags: display, screen, monitor, orientation

I need to rotate a screen, so I created in home directory a file */.xprofile*.
In this .xprofile file I wrote command:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-1 --rotate left
```

and it works properly. If I reboot full system it again will work properly.

BUT if I switch OFF the monitor power and switch ON the monitor power (but the operating system continues to work), screen rotation becomes default (normal).

For example:
I need left orientation of the screen.
For some reasons I switch off monitor power for 5 seconds, and after I switch ON the monitor power oriention is normal. But I still need left orientation of the screen.

How to permamently save the orientation of the screen regardless of the power  status of the monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved:**

I just cheked */etc/udev/rules.d* - udev event rules.

There was rule "60-drm.rules".
This rule ran the */usr/local/bin/drm-hotplug script.sh* every time the "monitor on" event occurred.

In this script was a code line: `sudo -u $user xrandr --output $monitor --auto`

So I changed this code to : `sudo -u $user xrandr --output $monitor --rotate left`

Thats all.